# Are these uses of infinitive phrases syntactic modiﬁers or syntactic complements, and of what?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, modifiers, grammatical-case, infinitive-constructions

I have two questions about the grammatical roles of the infinitive phrases in these two sentences:

1. He is the person **to contact** if you will need any advice.
2. There is a person **to connect** A PC to B PC.

#### My first question on *modiﬁers*

What does *to contact* modify in *the person to contact*? Is it working adjectively to modify *the person*?

#### My second question on *complements*

Is *to connect* not actually a modiﬁer in these but rather a complement, and if so, what is it the complement of?

Comment: [correction: if you need advice]

Comment: What @Lambie was mentioning in her brief correction is that you mustn’t say *if you **will** need any advice*. You cannot use *will* there in that *if* clause where you have placed it. Although native speakers can probably figure out what you seem to mean here, it is ungrammatical to us to have a *will* inside an *if* like this.

Comment: Yes. Inside an _if_ clause, _will_ can only mean "be willing to", which doesn't work with needing advice.

Comment: @JohnLawler Mostly, but there's also a use of *will* in antecedents/protases which means something like *it's already established at the current time*, normally used contrastively: "If the big tent *will* be there, then there's no need to us to take our waterproofs." Something of the flavour of emphatic *do*

Answer (score 5):

> [1] *He is the person* [ *to contact __ if you need any advice*].
>
> [2] *There is a person* [ *__ to connect A PC to B PC*].

In both examples, the bracketed element is an infinitival relative clause functioning as modifier of "person".

Non-*wh* infinitival relatives modify nouns and nominals in the same way that finite relatives do, though there is no relative phrase. Here the relativised element, marked by the gap notation '__', is object in [1] and subject in [2].

Most infinitival relatives have a modal meaning comparable with that expressed in finites by "can" and "should". Here the infinitival clauses modify "person" and are comparable to

> *He is the person that you can/should contact ...*
>
> *There is a person who can/should connect ...*